# How to use new disk space after extend attached SAN disk

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, windows

I have extended the space of my SAN vDisk from 1TB to 1.2TB, but Windows Explorer doesn't  show the new size.

After resize the vdisk in the SAN Manager, the **Disk Management** utility shows the 200GB unallocated space, then I resized the partition to use the unallocated space to get a 1.2TB partition, the process was succesfully, but in the Windows File Explorer the disk still have 1TB of total space.

Win version: **Windows Storage Server Enterprise 2007**.

Do I need to restart the server? How can I use the new extra space without rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dynamic disks, you should see it in explorer immediately. If you aren't, you might need to unmount and remount the LUN. Also, back in the day, SAN vendors used to ship host kits that would allow Windows servers to use the new space without an outage- I used one from an IBM LSI rebrand back in 2003 to do just this. Maybe you could check whether your storage vendor has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected to the server via a Terminal Services session try logging out and logging back in.

Even though you have extended the disk, your initial Windows Explorer launched via terminal services isn't smart enough to catch up on the change.

Comment: Pressing F5 should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Check and see if quotas are set on the volumes.  This took care of it for me.

To find the quotas, provided it is a Windows Server (mine 2012r2) is using the role of "File and Storage Services" look into the "File Server Resource Manager" management console > Quota Management > Quotas.
This may not be your solution especially if you don't have quotas or if the role of "File and Storage Services" is not selected for your system.

Comment: and what is the answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/518342)